# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException occurred when multiple user access this code

Tags: java, exception

Below is my code throwing `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`, which is being executed from servlet.

The exception occurred when multiple users try to access this code, and exception is at this line:

for(Message msg : dayWiseMsgs)

**Code:**

```
List<Message> newMessages = Collections.synchronizedList(
        new LinkedList<Message>());

try{

    logger.debug("Last Message Id = " + lastMessageId + 
            " For Chat Room=" + this.getName());

    List<List<Message>> allMessages = new LinkedList<List<Message>>(
            getMessages().values());


    for (List<Message> dayWiseMsgs : allMessages) {
         for(Message msg : dayWiseMsgs){
                    newMessages.add(msg);
                    this.setLastPushMessageId(msg.getId());                 
                }
            }        
        }
    }

    allMessages=null;

} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return newMessages;
```

Comment: Why you added  `for` loop and  `Iterator` on the same list?

Comment: What's the type of `getMessages()`? Is it accessed/modified from multiple threads?

Comment: getMessages() is a map <String,List<Messages>>

Comment: What about this `List<Message>` It contain Only  `Message` class why you again Iterate it?

Comment: i am not iteratting it again its a list of Messages. see this: List<List<Message>> allMessages

Comment: please udpate the title - make it more question-like.

Comment: Please ask a question, instead of just posting facts.

Answer (score 1):

[ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) occurs when `Collection` will be changed while some thread is traversing over it using `iterator`, which can happen in case of `multithreaded` as well as `single threaded` environment.

Talking about your code, this situation can happen when 1 thread is creating `newMessages` which is `synchronized` :

```
List<Message> newMessages = Collections.synchronizedList(
        new LinkedList<Message>());
```

while other is adding elements inside it:

```
newMessages.add(msg);
```

Moving the `synchronized` keyword at method level as below might work for you:

```
public synchronized List<Message> test() {
        List<Message> newMessages = new LinkedList<Message>();
        try {
            logger.debug("Last Message Id = " + lastMessageId
                    + " For Chat Room=" + this.getName());
            List<List<Message>> allMessages = new LinkedList<List<Message>>(
                    getMessages().values());
            for (List<Message> dayWiseMsgs : allMessages) {
                if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(dayWiseMsgs)
                        && lastMessageId < dayWiseMsgs.get(
                                dayWiseMsgs.size() - 1).getId()) {
                    for(Message message : dayWiseMsgs){
                        if (message!= null && message.getId() > lastMessageId) {
                            newMessages.add(message);
                            this.setLastPushMessageId(message.getId());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            allMessages = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newMessages;
    }
```

Add below dependency in your `classpath`:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: i tried this solution but still exception is occurring and some time it throws NullPointerException at same line : for(Message message : dayWiseMsgs)

Answer (score 0):

The `ConcurrentModificationException` is usually thrown when iterating through the list and in the same time usually another thread or even the same loop tries to modify (add / remove) the contents of the list.

now you have list of `newMessages` which you have made synchronized by calling `Collections.synchronizedList`
but you have not made `allMessages` synchronized, you are creating it using `newMessages` though.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it using for loop and synchronized:

what i did is: replaced foreach loop with simple for and modify the creation of list, made it synchronized :

```
chatRoom.getMessages().put(key, Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Message>()));



      List<List<Message>> allMessages =new LinkedList<List<Message>>(getMessages().values());

        for (List<Message> dayWiseMsgs : allMessages) {
            //List<Message> dayMsgs = new LinkedList<Message>(dayWiseMsgs);
            if (lastMessageId < dayWiseMsgs.get(dayWiseMsgs.size() - 1).getId()) {
                //for (Message msg : dayWiseMsgs) {
                Message msg = null;
                for(int i =0 ; i < dayWiseMsgs.size() ; i++){
                    msg = dayWiseMsgs.get(i);
                    if (msg.getId() > lastMessageId ) {
                        newMessages.add(msg);
                        this.setLastPushMessageId(msg.getId());

                    }
                }

            }
        }
```